# How write css rules in Sass?

Tags: sass

How write in short form this css rules in sass?

```
.w_50 .grid li .player .approved,.w_51 .grid li .player .approved{margin: 3px 3px 6px 9px;}
```

Comment: You mean , short?¿ not show....?¿

Comment: Yes, sorry for my english :)

Comment: There is no way to actually _shorten_ this, as all the steps _do_ need to be mentioned _somewhere_. SASS allows you, however, to nest all the steps and add multiple styles inside these layers without repeating the parent selectors, so it's output will include something like the above, but you still have to define all the rules and levels, even in SASS.

Comment: Valid CSS is valid SCSS, what you have is already correct.  SO is not a code optimization, refactoring, or translation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simply answer, you can't, not really. The advantage of something like SASS is that you can omit repeating the same things over and over, but for a single CSS style rule there is very little advantage. The most you could do is:

```
.w_50, .w_51 {
    .grid li .player .approved { margin: 3px 3px 6px 9px; }
}
```

But it is hard to argue that this is shorter. Where SASS becomes useful is if you nest your properties and define style in them, so you do not have to repeat yourself. For Example:

```
article {
    padding: 20px;
    h1 { color: red; }
    p { margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```

This will output:

```
article { padding: 20px; }
article h1 { color: red; } 
article p { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Again, though, not much effort is saved here but you can see when you nest a couple more things, or when your stylesheets get expansive, that you do *not* have to repeatedly write `article` in front of every rule. On top of that, SASS (and LESS as well) allow for some simple logic to repeat things, or use variables (which will make it easy to change a color scheme without having to find every instance of a color).

Read up on SASS at sass-lang.com to find out about the *actual* **major** improvements a preprocessor can provide to you.

Comment: Cool solution. Thanks!